# d3 update old scale when pan and zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3. When do pan and zoom with `d3v4`, I noticed we always have to create new scale based on the `d3.event.transform` and apply the new scale to everything rather than replace the old scale with new and apply the old scale again. For example, this zoom function works perfect:

```
function zoomFunction(){
  // create new scale ojects based on event
  var new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xAxisScale)
  var new_yScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yAxisScale)
  console.log(d3.event.transform)

  // update axes
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(new_xScale));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(new_yScale));

  // update circle
  circles.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
};
```

This zoom function screws everything:

```
function zoomFunction(){
  // create new scale ojects based on event
  var new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xAxisScale)
  var new_yScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yAxisScale)
  xAxisScale = new_xScale;
  yAxisScale = new_yScale;
  console.log(d3.event.transform)

  // update axes
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(xAxisScale));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(yAxisScale));

  // update circle
  circles.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
};
```

The full example is here: https://bl.ocks.org/rutgerhofste/5bd5b06f7817f0ff3ba1daa64dee629d

The reason I want to use the new scale to replace the old one is that in my case a lot of parts of svg are related to scale. If I simply change the old scale, those binded events will work perfectly. I don't want to reclaim everything in my zoomFunction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you wish to change

`xAxisScale = new_xScale;
 yAxisScale = new_yScale;`

inside the zoom function for some reason.

If you do it the rescale will not work as expected.

```
  var new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xAxisScale)
  var new_yScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yAxisScale)
```

**Reason:** xAxisScale andyAxisScale should be the original, because the rescale is calculated based/relative to the original scale value.

One way to get around this would be to make a copy of the original 
x  and y scale.

```
// create scale objects
var xAxisScale =d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-200,-100])
  .range([0,width]);

var yAxisScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-10,-20])
  .range([height,0]);

//make a copy of the scales
var copyX = xAxisScale.copy();  
var copyY = yAxisScale.copy();  
// create axis objects
```

Next in your zoomFunction do :

```
function zoomFunction(){
  // create new scale ojects based on event
  var new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(copyX)
  var new_yScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(copyY)
  //changing scale due to some reason.
  xAxisScale = new_xScale;
  yAxisScale = new_yScale;

  // update axes
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(xAxisScale));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(yAxisScale));

  // update circle
  circles.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
};
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ti61IzNgBeKOc3YnPIE6?p=preview)

Comment: This answer solved my problem perfectly. Thank you a lot! Just to make sure I understand it, every pan and zoom process is based on the original scale which determines the initial positions and range rather than the most current scale right?